# How to designate thread to computer core in haskell parallel pragram?

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing

I wanna know whether we can designate threads to the core of computer in haskell?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`forkOn`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Concurrent.html#v%3aforkOn) instead of `forkIO`:

> Like `forkIO`, but lets you specify on which processor the thread should run. Unlike a `forkIO` thread, a thread created by `forkOn` will stay on the same processor for its entire lifetime (`forkIO` threads can migrate between processors according to the scheduling policy). `forkOn` is useful for overriding the scheduling policy when you know in advance how best to distribute the threads.

Don't forget that you need to set the capability with either `-N[x]` or `setNumCapabilities`.